# Cart Throb - Canada Post live rates errors

Tags: cartthrob

Trying to get CPC live rates working and I am getting this error

Couldn't connect to host (7)

I get this on the front end AND the back end.  My CPC id has been set up and verified.  Doesn't matter if I have test or live set as the status same error.

And when this error shows up I get locked out of the admin section of the site.  The ONLY way to get back in is to manually remove the CPC ID# from the database.

IS there anyone out there who has the Canada Post live rates working with Cart Throb?  I am getting little help over at the CT forums as shipping plugins are not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved but opening port 30000 on my server

Answer (score 5):

Canada Post completely changed their [e-commerce platform API](http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/ecomplatforms/default.jsf) in June of this year. I know the CartThrob plugin was in development quite awhile before that, and at that, I don't think it was given much attention. So my bet is it was never updated.

I keep meaning to delve into building my own for the new API, as I am in Canada and work with many Canadian clients. But I *mean* to do a lot of things, ha.

Comment: The Canadian Post plugin file shows a last modified date of 03/26/12

Comment: @derek Hogue, did you ever get a Canada Post plugin working?

Comment: Afraid not Sean.